# Tesseract not installing correctly on python on Mac OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr

The problem seems to be stemming from this below, but unsure what is causing it exactly since the code its referring to is something I didn't write and assume is a part of a module somewhere? I'm on a mac operating MacOSX 10.14 using Anaconda for Python if that helps.

```
File "/Users/name/Desktop/Python/OCRTest.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tesseract

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tesseract/__init__.py", line 34
    print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried reinstalling numerous modules related to Tesseract but i'll admit i'm not fully aware of what I am installing. Usually I would just use the import command but since this is not a part of the standard Python library I needed to install it.

I have used the following commands in terminal with success so believe I do have the required modules as well as this "Pillow" program.

```
pip install pytesseract
pip install Images
pip install pytesser
```

(Unsure if I need that last one but one site said I did so got it anyways)

This is the code i'm using, its just a test program to get this working.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import tesseract
import pytesser

direct = "/Users/name/Desktop/test.png"
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(direct))
```

This should return the text "Rearrange" from an image file I have, its printed text so shouldn't be giving it any major problems.

Comment: The code giving an error seems like python2, perhaps because you're using `pip` to install. Perhaps try to use conda's `conda install`?